# Howto send UDP Broadcast messages for Module running on Azure IoT Runtime

Tags: udp, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I need to send a UDP Broadcast to the network connected to my device from an Container running as a module inside the **Azure IoT Edge Runtime**.

I've exported my udp port in the module configuration

```
{
  "ExposedPorts": {
    "7808/udp": {}
  },
  "HostConfig": {
    "PortBindings": {
      "7808/udp": [
        {
          "HostPort": "7808"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Unicasts work fine. But i can't send a Broadcast to the outside world.

I've already tried to use the devices dedicated network broadcast IP without success.

Sample Code:

```cs
// initialize UdpClient
var ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, SharedPort);;
var _exclusiveConn = new UdpClient { ExclusiveAddressUse = true };
_exclusiveConn.Client.Bind(ep);
_exclusiveConn.EnableBroadcast = true;

// send
_exclusiveConn.Send(buffer, bufferlength, ep);
```

Comment: which SDK you are using ie : c#,python etc and could you share the reference you used

Comment: I'm using c# SDK

Answer (score 0):

- Using [Reference](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2021/05/12/azure-iot-edge-udp-client-module/) for Azure IoT Edge UDP Client module.

**Code:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    private const int SharedPort = 7808;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Broadcast address for IPv4
            var broadcastAddress = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255"), SharedPort);

            // Initialize UdpClient
            var udpClient = new UdpClient { ExclusiveAddressUse = false }; // Allow multiple clients to bind to the same port
            udpClient.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, SharedPort));
            udpClient.EnableBroadcast = true;

            // Message to send
            string message = "Hello, Broadcast World!";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

            // Send the UDP broadcast message
            udpClient.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, broadcastAddress);

            Console.WriteLine("UDP broadcast message sent: " + message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

- For more details refer Azure IoT Edge UDP Client [module](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2021/05/12/azure-iot-edge-udp-client-module/) and [git](https://github.com/iot-edge-foundation/iot-edge-udp-client)

Comment: this was already working in my implementation. But what I am struggling is, that the broadcast that is sent from within my Module in my Azure IoT Runtime should be forewarded to my physical network on my device.

Comment: @romanruthofer Hope this reference [helps](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-edge/how-to-deploy-modules-portal.md)